# Copy text to clipboard from jsf / primefaces doesnt always work

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces, zclip

The resolution for **Copy text to clipboard from jsf / primefaces** mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320462/copy-text-to-clipboard-from-jsf-primefaces) works as it is but seems to have some issue for me please find my code below:

```
    <h:outputScript library="default" name="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>
    <h:outputScript library="default" name="js/jquery.zclip.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('a#copy_coupon_code').zclip({
        path:"#{resource['default:js/ZeroClipboard.swf']}",
        copy:$('span#offer_details_form:coupon_code').text()
    });
    });
    </script>                    
<h:outputText id="coupon_code" value="ABCD11" />
<a id="copy_coupon_code" href="#">Copy coupon and redirect</a>
```

This is how the code looks in the browser:
[image]

Copy to clipboard is not working, any help is greatly appreciated.....

Comment: Can you please elaborate on separated by 2. mean?

Comment: Open firebug in Firefox or developer tools in your browser and check the html markup for the ids.

Comment: There is some script problem in your code, like @Ravi said, look the firebug to find it.

Comment: @Ravi I tired to debug the code here & updated the question with the findings. Let me know if you have any clue....

Comment: You could always make a command button for copy to clipboard? See here  http://ovaraksin.blogspot.ie/2012/10/copy-to-clipboard-feature-in-web.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known problem to integrate JSF and jQuery,because jsf use colon `:` character to present component's id, and the colon `:` character is special character(the colon `:` is reserved for jQuery selector) so you have to escape by placing two backslashes in front of it :

```
$('span#offer_details_form\\:coupon_code')
```

I have just tested and it work fine(download zClip from [here](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/#download)):

```
<h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.zclip.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#copylink').zclip({
                    path:"#{resource['js:ZeroClipboard.swf']}",
                    copy:$('#myform\\:txt1').text()
                });
            });
        </script>
        <h:form id="myform">
            <p:panel>
                <h:outputText id="txt1" value="Stackoverflow"/>
                <a id="copylink" href="#">Copy Description</a>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

**and result:**

[image]

Comment: I'm using mobile, so i can not show more information, sorry for that.

Comment: Following was the fix for the issue, this fix was provided by RongNK, thanks a lot @RongNK <a style="position: relative" id="copylink" href="#"...